# Как сделать стартовую страницу в Android

Tags: java, android

Создаю приложение из двух страниц и хочу, чтобы вторая страница открывалась при запуске приложения. Как это реализовать в android?

Comment: А что вы таки имеет в виду под "вторая страница"?

Comment: думаю, что страница это активити.

Comment: Если оставить как есть, то практически оба ответа ниже верны. Если уточнить детали вопроса, то какой-то будет требуемым.))

Comment: "Как сделать стартовую страницу в Android studio." по такому заголовку можно говорить что он хочет чтобы андроид студия стартовала с двумя вкладками:) и во второй что-то.

Answer (score 4):

```
setContentView(R.layout.twoActivity);
```

Answer (score 1):

В манифесте меняйте имя первой Activity на ваше. Например было MainActivity меняем на TwoActivity.

Answer (score 1):

В manifeste надо изменить

```
<activity android:name=".ВТОРАЯ СТРАНИЦА">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ВТОРАЯ СТРАНИЦА" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

на следующее!

```
<activity android:name=".ВТОРАЯ СТРАНИЦА">
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

         <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
</activity>
```